# What is the most optimal way for a 2D square matrix with alternate 1's and 0's in C

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

something like below for example:

```
| 0 1 0 1 0 |
| 1 0 1 0 1 |
| 0 1 0 1 0 |
| 1 0 1 0 1 |
| 0 1 0 1 0 |
```

Is the following a good approach, but this would still not produce the required output:

```
void AltBitArray(int array[][4], int size)
{
  int row, column;
  int val = 0;

  for (row = 0; row < size; row++) {
    for (column = 0; column < size; column++) {
      if (val == 0) {
        array[row][column] = val;
        val = 1;
      }
      else
      {
        array[row][column] = val;
        val = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am getting the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Y would convert the verbose code as following:

```
  for (row = 0; row < size; row++) {
    for (column = 0; column < size; column++) {
      if (val == 0) {
        array[row][column] = val;
        val = 1;
      }
      else
      {
        array[row][column] = val;
        val = 0;
      }
    }
  }
```

into following

```
  for (row = 0; row < size; row++) {
    for (column = 0; column < size; column++) {
      array[row][column] = val;
      val = val ^ 1; // or with val = 1 - val;
    }
}
```

Here is a working demo
https://ideone.com/AEpRjH

```
// Output
0 1 0 1 0 
1 0 1 0 1 
0 1 0 1 0 
1 0 1 0 1 
0 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: Hi Johirul, thanks but I think you meant val ^= 1; But that would still not generate the required output.